# Yii mpdf render not working when the webpage contains images and buttons

Tags: pdf, yii, mpdf

I need to convert a html page(with images, buttons and a lot of css) to PDF and I'm using yii. 
I chose mPDF over HTML2PDF(no particular reason for that.) When I render a page for converting to PDF, the PDF doesn't load, but when I use renderPartial, the page loads(only the html part works here).

I want the page to be completely converted to PDF and I tried going through the mPDF documentation but I couldn't 'find' anything useful.

this is my code :

```
$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();


            $mPDF1->WriteHTML(
                        $this->render('render_page',
                                array( ...),
                            true ));

            //Output PDF file
            $mPDF1->Output();
```

**Please let me know if I have to provide more informations...**

Comment: Please let me know the reason if you are downvoting this question

Comment: Try using the image as background image of the related div

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work.. I can't load any buttons either. If I use render instead of renderPartial, the page doesn't load and gives me a connection error.